# how to connect to oracle free cloud using mobaxterm?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, mobaxterm

I'm trying to connect to oracle free cloud using mobaxterm but I'm receiving:

```
Unable to use key file "X:\\oracleCloud\\ssh-key-2020-10-11.key" (OpenSSH private key)

No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

Session stopped
    - Press <return> to exit tab
    - Press R to restart session
    - Press S to save terminal output to file
```

I used the public ip + opc (as it's centos based machine), as well as the private key that was generated when I created the instance.
Any idea on what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to be able to connect, I generated a ssh key pair using puttygen. Seems the generated ones from oracle were the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Mobaxterm 20. The key file worked fine in normal SSH, but with MobaXterm I received the same error message as you.

I've updated to MobaXTerm v 22.1 and it works fine